# $A^{T}A$ is diagonal. What can I say about $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Is there any special property about the elements of $A$ if $A^{T}A$ is diagonal? I imagine you need some sort of symmetry but I can't see what it should be.

Edit: Sorry, maybe it's better phrased this way. If $A$ is $3 \times 3$, it has nine elements. If $A^{T}A$ is diagonal, how many parameters do I now need to specify $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your second question: if $A$ is $3x3$ and satisfies $A^T A = D$ for some diagonal matrix $D$, it satisfies 6 additional constraints (namely the equations from the off-diagonal terms in $A^T A = D$). Since $A^T A$ is symmetric, only $3$ of these constraints are independent, so in total we need $9-3=6$ parameters to specify $A$.

Answer (score 5):

The columns of $A$ are orthogonal to each other. So $A=OD$ where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix $OO^T=I$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: In this case we get (if $O$ is orthogonal) $OO^T = I$. Can ever occour that $AA^T \neq I$ for any (real) matrix $A$?

Comment: Sure, take any matrix $A$ satisfying $AA^T = I$ and multiply its entries by $\lambda$. The result is a matrix satisfying $(\lambda A) (\lambda A)^T = \lambda^2 I$. But Micheal already gave you the general form of such a matrix, $A= OD$.

Comment: This is nice, but I have edited my question to make it more clear. How does the symmetry reduce the number of elements (or parameters needed to specify A) change with this condition. Thanks!